# Data Ordering from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have asked this question, but have had not answer that worked and then question was moved and or misunderstood - so no i ask with screenshots.

My issue is this. I have data stored in db as shown in screenshot here
[image: Database View]

By using query below i am trying to display listing by time ascending

```
$lookup = dbquery("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE book_date='".$findme."' ORDER BY book_time DESC");
```

But it does not sort correctly. Shows as below.

[image: Page view]

Can you please help me with this. As you can see date & time are stored in VARCHAR fields as timestamp.

Comment: Please don't just ask the same question again. Look at the comments below your other version of this question. Edit that question as suggested. By editing the question, it will show up at the top of the questions list again.

Comment: It is not really helpful that both screenshots are about different data. None of the persons on the first corresponds with one on the second.

Comment: does not matter the names. i just want you to see the structure of db.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select * from bookings  WHERE book_date='".$findme."' order by FROM_UNIXTIME(book_time) asc;
```

Comment: This did not work. Still same..

Comment: i edited the code, you can try again

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Rogin, still no luck...

Comment: did you run the query in mysql?